# finding four types of search criteria using regex

Tags: python, regex

```
match = re.search("/versions", "/this/path/is/versions")
```

this gives me a match found, however I have multiple search criteria .

i.e. I want to find out match for these four category.
 if path ends with /versions or /versions/ or /pageout or /pageout/

is it possible to do with regex in python or do you recommend using ends with with 4 types.

Comment: `match = re.search("/(versions|pageout)/?$", your_string)`

Comment: ^^ Either that or: `your_string.endswith(('/versions', '/versions/', /pageout', '/pageout/))`. Not sure what would be beneficial. If you want to know what is recommended I suggest you do a benchmark test?

Comment: whichever is more intuitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `(?m)/(?:(versions)|pageout)(/)?$`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eIrdCs/1)

features:

- group 1 matched, then `versions` else `pageout`
- group 2 matched, then trailing `/` else nothing trailing